# Recursive exponentiation to code

Tags: performance, math, numbers, logic, exponent

I had a math question that featured in an olymipad somehwere and I am trying to implement it question in code. The thing is, I cant figure out the logic to this problem.

The question is,

9^(9^(9^(9^...... 1001 times....))). What are the final 5 digits in the answer?

I'd be glad if someone could tell me how to do this. Bear in mind that since I need to implement this in code, a solution which takes a lesser number of steps and therefore is more optimal in terms of complexity is favourable to me.

However, if you have any approach that gets to the right solution, I'd like to know that as well, since I havent been able to get my head around this one.

Comment: trivial thing asked many times before see `modpow(9,1001,100000);` look for modular arithmetics and power

Comment: @Spektre Duuuuude ... that's sick ! But, performance wise, it'll suck :). First, link to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Second, I was wrong,it took 2 milliseconds to compute (60009).

Comment: @SPecktre 
Yes exactly, I really wanted an optimal solution to the question

Comment: @Spektre: The question is not about 9^1001. It is about the tower 9^9^9^9...^9 with 1001 9s. At least, that's the type of question asked on math olympiads. It looks like a lot of people here are more interested in 9^1001.

Comment: @Noctis, D.Lovell's solution leads to final digits as 80009. Just in case you wanted to recheck it :)

Comment: I'm sorry. My answer was wrong. I ran in a different track because of the comment. I'll see if I can give a better one, or just remove it. **D Lowel** might be on the money though.

Comment: Hint: if such power tower has more than 15 floors, result will be the same.  This is because φ(φ(...φ(10^5)..))=1, where φ (Euler's totient) is repeated 15 times.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: and three steps before the totient value is 8, and `9^n mod 8=1` for all integers n, so that the result will be the same starting with 12 floors of the tower.

Comment: @LutzL - You're right.

Comment: ow I see it is `^` instead of `*` hehe where I left my eyes :) but anyway it is still simple `int i,x; for (x=9,i=0;i<1000;i++) x=modpow(x,9,100000);` should have to do (it took around 0.53 ms on mine average machine)

Comment: @Spektre: That calculates ((9^9)^9)... which is not 9^(9^(...9^9)). As I mentioned in my answer, it is not automatic that it is enough to track intermediate results mod 100000 although that is the case for towers of 9s.

Comment: @DouglasZare yep that is far more complicated ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like some other answers compute 9^1001. This is **not** the problem posed. That would be far too simple for an olympiad problem.

Define T(a,n) so that T(a,1) = a, and T(a,n) = a^T(a,n-1). This is called [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). The problem asked for T(9,1001) mod 100,000.

To do the actual problem, it isn't obvious which modulus to use. It's not always that T(a,n) mod m is T(a,n mod m) mod m. For example, T(2,3) = 2^2^2 = 2^4 = 16. T(2,4) = 2^16 = 65536. Mod 10, you can't just compute T(2,3) mod 10 = 6 and then 2^6 mod 10 = 64 mod 10 = 4. The last digit of T(2,4)=65536 is 6, not 4.

However, you can work out that 9^2500 = 1 mod 100000, so 9^100000 = 1 mod 100000, too. (By the Chinese Remainder Theorem you can analyze powers of 9 mod 2^5 and 5^5.) So, you only need to keep track of the value of T(9,n) mod 2500 or 100000 to determine T(9,1001) mod 100000. Compute t = T(9,1000) mod 2500, and then compute powermod(9,t,100000).

In fact, the function which maps n to 9^n mod 100000 settles down rapidly to a fixed point at 45289. 9^9 mod 2500 is 489, 9^489 mod 2500 is 2289, 9^2289 mod 2500 is 289, and 9^289 mod 2500 is 289 again. Since 9^289 mod 100000 is 45289, T(9,4), T(9,5), ..., T(9,1001) all end in 45289.

---

Edit: Let me flesh out Egor Skriptunoff's comment. Powers of 9 mod 10^5 cycle with period dividing phi(10^5)=40000, where phi is the [Euler Totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function). So, we only need to determine T(9,1000) mod 40000. Powers of 9 mod 40000 cycle with period dividing phi(40000) =16000, so we only need to find T(9,999) mod 16000, etc. Since phi iterated 15 times on 10^5 is 1, we know the value of any power of 9 mod phi^15(10^5), and so T(9,16) = T(9,n) mod 10^5 for any greater n.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and since the math is out of my depth, does my updated answer seems correct ?

Comment: @Noctis: It should work. Minor problem: It looks like you are calculating T(9,1002) mod 100000, although that gives the same value. You might initialize result to 1 instead of 9. The main issue is that, while in this case it's ok to keep track of T(9,n) mod 100000, the analogous statement is not always true.